# Winged Sonobe octahedron assembly

Tags: origami, unit-origami

I can make a winged sonobe cube and the winged sonobe piece. I learnt to do this from our origami book. The book states you can use twelve pieces to make an octahedron.

We have spent quite some time trying to puzzle out how to do this without success. I then tried to google a tutorial but can only find tutorials for the normal sonobe piece octahedrons.

Does anyone know how to build an octahedron from the winged sonobe pieces?

Comment: Can you expand on what exactly the problem is? Is it adding the final modules, merely connecting single modules together or something different? Not required but do you have the name of the book you got this tutorial from? I love sonobe modules so I would like to try this myself. What size paper are you using? Using larger squares will likely give you a better grasp on the assembly (even if you only make a few to start).

Comment: Possibly no help at all, but someone put [a picture of one up on deviantart](http://saston.deviantart.com/art/Winged-Sonobe-Octahedron-119110085) and mentioned a high frustration level.

Comment: @Matt  I can make the seperate units without a problem. I can put them together into a cube without (much) trouble too but the 12 piece one is killing me. I think smaller size is actually better as you can hold them more easily...you really have to fumble to fit them all together. The book is is ZAP origami creations.

Comment: I want to help with this but I am having trouble finding instruction for the module. I can only find a couple of pictures for it. Do you have a picture of the finished model just to be sure what I am looking for. I have a modular origami book at home but I don't recall any unit called this.

Comment: Have you ever folded a 12-unit assembly of some other Sonobe unit? The method is quite standard so it's an important question whether the issue arises with this particular Sonobe variation or perhaps with going from a cube to an octahedral assembly with any Sonobe unit?

Answer (score 1):

[image: 3 photo's. two showing a single winged sonobe. One flat one folded a third photo of 3 units assembled together]
Image is mine. I took it for this answer.
As you have stated you can make a cube expect you can get to the point with the three pieces together. 
Which for me shows where to put the next 6. Is the adding the last 3 units the point where you get stuck?
If so i find assembling the last three pieces together and then putting them in easier.

I don't know the terminology I do know how to make a octahedron.

Make sure all your sonobe's are the same. It doesn't matter if they all 'lean' left or right but you need 12 the same.