# How do you make the winged sonobe module?

Tags: origami, unit-origami

This is what a winged sonobe polyhedral looks like:

[image: Winged sonobe polyhedral]

<sup>Image from [DeviantArt](http://piplup-fangirl66.deviantart.com/art/winged-sonobe-187692620) by [Piplup-fangirl66](http://piplup-fangirl66.deviantart.com/)</sup>

This should not be that hard but I cannot, for the life of me, find a resource online that tells me how to make this without making a purchase. [Another question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/winged-sonobe-octahedron-assembly) on this topic mentions about a book called: [*Zap! Origami Creations*](http://www.booktopia.com.au/zap-origami-creations-matthew-gardiner/prod9781488925450.html;jsessionid=TYQLXdeFHLNQ7pud-KQSQsN4.undefined) which I do not own, nor can find a reference to what I am looking for. There is even a [video which "explains" how to make one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vn4F6WXoHPA) but it ends up just being a fake out involving useless folds and a magic reveal. (I only include it to show what I have looked for. I would not waste your time watching it.)

I have a hard copy of a great book: [*Modular Origami Polyhedra*](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Modular_Origami_Polyhedra.html?id=xeK7AQAAQBAJ&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y) but it does not cover this unit.

Is it possible that this could be found with a different name?

I am trying to avoid having to buy a book to get the fold instructions. Surely this is something that is shareable with proper attribution?

Answer (score 3):

Take two ordinary modules and join them together with one of their tabs in one of the other's pockets, forming the analogue of a triangular pyramid but with two sides only.

You obtain a subassembly that looks and works like a single Sonobe module, with the same tabs and pockets in the same position (the unused half of each module) and an additional triangular fin (formed by the joined halves of the modules) protruding from the outer side.

Make a plain old pyramidated octahedron with these assemblies replacing the regular modules and you'll get the 8 pyramids and 12 fins in the photo.